# How to change( and later restore) default context menu in textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, default

I wanted to change default textbox context menu, so I created my own menu and them I assigned it like that

```
texbox.ContextMenu = myContextMenu
```

However I don't know how to restore default textbox menu (in a runtime). I need myContextMenu to show only when I click textbox with right mouse button (while holding Control button). In other cases I need default textbox contextmenu to show.
Is it possible ??

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example given by Microsoft:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750420.aspx

For the record, here is the way to do this using WinForms:

```
public partial class TextBoxContextMenuDemo : Form
{
    ContextMenu mnuContextDefault;
    ContextMenu mnuContextAlt;

    MenuItem mnuItmAltMenuTest;

    public TextBoxContextMenuDemo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeAltContextMenu();
    }

    private void InitializeAltContextMenu()
    {
        mnuContextDefault = new ContextMenu();
        mnuContextDefault = this.TextBox1.ContextMenu;

        mnuItmAltMenuTest = new MenuItem();
        mnuItmAltMenuTest.Index = -1;
        mnuItmAltMenuTest.Text = "Test Menu Item";
        mnuItmAltMenuTest.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.mnuItmAltMenuTest_Click);

        mnuContextAlt = new ContextMenu();
        mnuContextAlt.MenuItems.Add(mnuItmAltMenuTest);
    }

    private void TextBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if ((Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control))
            {
                this.TextBox1.ContextMenu = mnuContextAlt;
                TextBox1.ContextMenu.Show(TextBox1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            }
            else
            {
                this.TextBox1.ContextMenu = mnuContextDefault;
            }
        }
    }

    private void mnuItmAltMenuTest_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked the alternate test menu item!");
    }
}
```

HTH!

Comment: Ugh, more badly written MSDN sample code. Among other problems, it's quite redundant to initialize `mnuContextDefault` with a *new* `ContextMenu` object, and then immediately set it to `TextBox1.ContextMenu`. And this code never restores the default context menu, despite going through so much trouble to save it.

Comment: Wait...this sample code *isn't* from the linked MSDN article. That doesn't say anything like what you posted here. Where did you get this?

Comment: @CodyGray I wrote this code.  I apologize for the error which you have pointed out (redundant initialization).  I would like to point out that the code _does_ restore the default context menu if the ctrl button is not pressed when right-clicking the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

It would actually be more difficult to do than it would first seem.  I believe that the default context menu is part of the actual template of the control.

The simplest approach, if you only want Cut/Copy/Paste, is to create a second ContextMenu implementing those options.  If you do, you can use the built in [ApplicationCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) to implement not only the functionality, but also to automatically localize this ContextMenu.

Comment: I try this, however maybe I can somehow copy default menu to separate object ? Maybe with xaml reader or sth?

Answer (score 0):

You could just set the ContextMenu-Property to null. Also the OnContextMenuOpening event can help you.